# Eclipse missing some Preferences menu items

Tags: eclipse, menu

I have Eclipse 3.0 recently installed on a desktop and a laptop. The laptop installation is missing several menu items under Window/Preferences that appear under the desktop. The missing items include:

Data Management
Plug-in Development
Remote Systems 
Servers
terminal
Web
Web services

I installed them both from Eclipse.org at about the same time. How can they have different menus. I tried reinstalling on the desktop, but there was no change.

How can I get these menus to match?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one install might be "classic" while the other is "J2EE"... did you install them from the same download or were they separate?